# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python, typeerror

I am a beginner in Python and am working on an assignment.  I keep getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'` even after researching the error and applying the suggested fixes.  I'm not looking for anyone to hand me a solution, but I would appreciate a second look.  I'm missing something but I don't know what.  This is the section of code I'm having trouble with:

```
month = 0
interestYDT = 0
balance = int(raw_input ("Enter balance on credit card: "))
annualInterestRate = float(raw_input ("Enter annual interest rate as a decimal: "))
monthlyPaymentRate = float(raw_input ("Enter minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))
previousbalance = balance
#
def monthlyInterestRate(annualInterestRate):
    return float(annualInterestRate/12)
#
if month <= 12:
    def minimumMonthlyPayment(previousbalance):
        return (previousbalance * monthlyPaymentRate)
    def monthlyInterest(monthlyInterestRate):
        return (1 + monthlyInterestRate)
    minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment
    monInt = monthlyInterest
    newbalance = ((previousbalance - minMonPay) * (monInt))
    interestYDT = (interestYTD + montInt)
    previousbalance = (newbalance)
    print ''
    print ('Month:' (month))
    print ('Minimum monthly payment: $ ' (round(minimumMonthlyPayment, 2)))
    print ('Remainging balance: $ ' (round(newbalance, 2)))
    print ' '
    month = (month + 1)
```

This is the entire error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karla/Documents/_MIT 600X Introduction to CS and Prog/Assignments/Week2/kmarciszewski_week2_Problemset_Problem1.py", line 33, in <module>
    newbalance = ((previousbalance - minMonPay) * (monInt))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'
```

I'd really appreciate any insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to call a function you must add parens after the function name, as well as any required parameters.

In these two lines

```
minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment
monInt = monthlyInterest
```

you assign the functions to the names minMonPay, monInt, but you don't actually call them. Rather, you would need to write something like:

```
minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment(previousBalance)
monInt = monthlyInterest(monthlyInterestRate)
```

This definition

```
def minimumMonthlyPayment(previousbalance):
    return (previousbalance * monthlyPaymentRate)
```

gives you a function that takes one parameter and calls it previousBalance. It has nothing to do with the variable you created earlier in your code. In fact, I suggest you rename it, it can only serve to confuse you as a beginner.

Further, the functions you've created are so simple, and only used once each, that it might be in your interest to remove them and inline the code.

```
# OLD CODE
def minimumMonthlyPayment(previousbalance):
    return (previousbalance * monthlyPaymentRate)
def monthlyInterest(monthlyInterestRate):
    return (1 + monthlyInterestRate)
minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment
monInt = monthlyInterest

# NEW CODE
minMonPay = previousbalance * monthlyPaymentRate
monInt = 1 + monthlyInterestRate
```

Dont forget to update the line that incorrectly uses the minimumMonthlyPayment function if you do this.

```
# OLD CODE
print ('Minimum monthly payment: $ ' (round(minimumMonthlyPayment, 2)))

# NEW CODE
print ('Minimum monthly payment: $ ' (round(minMonPay, 2)))
```

Comment: I guess I don't have a firm grasp on when to use methods.  I took your suggestion and removed them, but now it's not asking for any input.  I haven't removed all the old coding, just commented it out for now. and this is what I have:

Comment: @KMarciszewski added one more thing. If you get new problems, please post the error message

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, at present.  I'm not getting anything at all.  It's not asking for input or anything else.

Comment: @KMarciszewski I suspect the problem you had is solved, so this question is answered. You now have a new problem, somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line `minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment` it looks to me like you are assigning a variable to a method rather than calling the method.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  As eakron stated, my problem has been solved.  but now I have a new one.  I do have one last question for this post, can you suggest some good Python books that I might read to help me get a firmer grounding?  Thanks, again.

Comment: @KMarciszewski [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is quite possibly the best free book you can get. Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the check sign.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and it looks like you are assigning a function to a variable and then trying to minus a function from a value.

You define the function 'minimumMonthlyPayment(previousbalance)', but then you assign the function to the variable 'minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment'.  Then later you say previousBalance - minMonPay.  What I think you meant to do was:

minMonPay = minimumMonthlyPayment(previousbalance)

Hope that helps.