# Why does this method not return a value?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 30
        self.b = 10
    def sumit(self):
        return self.a + self.b

giventhing = Thing
print(giventhing.sumit/2)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function and 'int'
```

Comment: You need to call the function..

Comment: As a side note: You tagged this `python-2.7`, but I'm pretty sure you're using Python 3, not 2.7. In Python 2, the error would be complaining about an unbound instancemethod, not a function.

Comment: @abarnert You're totally right, and also if the tag is `python-2.7` so why you want to use parenthesis for `print`?

Comment: `python-2` print works both for brackets and without brackets. It is `python-3` that gives error if the brackets are not used.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, good catch. A mod can change it if they like.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Yes, but it's a bit misleading to use the parens in 2.7, unless you're using `from __future__ import print_function`. Someone else reading your code will _think_ it's for Python 3 even though it isn't. Not to mention that at some point you're going to write `print(x, y)` and then wonder by you got `('hello', 'world')` as the output instead of `hello world`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923264/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sumit` is a function: you need to call it with brackets: `print(giventhing.sumit()/2)`

Comment: Doh, it had to be something like that.

Comment: You also want to do `giventhing = Thing()` to instantiate an instance of `Thing`

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here:

- `sumit` is an instance method, so you need to call it on an instance, not a class (or type).
- To execute callables, such as methods, you need to use the propert syntax, which is `method()`, **note the () at the end**.

Doing `giventhing = Thing` won't give you an instance, it will give you a reference to the class/type itself, which is only useful if you want to operate with class members, which is not your use case.

Doing `giventhing.sumit / 2`, won't divide the result of `sumit` by 2. In fact, `giventhing.sumit` will yield a reference to the function itself, not its result. You *need to call* the function in order to get its return value, i.e. `sumit()`

Fixed code:

```
giventhing = Thing()          # You need an instance of Thing
print(giventhing.sumit() / 2) # You need to actually call sumit on the instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are type of function you need to first call it

So need:

```
giventhing = Thing()
print(giventhing.sumit()/2)
```

So totally need parentheses

Here's an example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
    def out(self):
        return self.a

>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a=A(1)
>>> a.out
<bound method A.out of <__main__.A object at 0x0000005F9D177EB8>>
>>> a.out()
1
>>>
```